# Dynamically configure print settings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class like this in my WPF application, here I want to assign the Print settings like the Page size, tray  without showing the dialogbox to the user. 
I am able to get set the other values except for the Print tray  it would be of great help if anyone could help me on this.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

public class Print
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Print"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Print() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputStream">The output stream.</param>
    public void PrintDocument(MemoryStream outputStream)
    {
        FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

        TextRange tr = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
        tr.Load(outputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);

        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();



        fd.PageHeight = printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight;
        fd.PageWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth;
        fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(25);

        fd.ColumnGap = 0;
        fd.ColumnWidth = (fd.PageWidth -
                               fd.ColumnGap -
                               fd.PagePadding.Left -
                               fd.PagePadding.Right);

        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {              
            IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = fd;
            idpSource.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size { Height = 600, Width = 600 };
            printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Document");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668873/how-do-i-set-paper-type-while-using-printerdialog/8036419#8036419)

Comment: I am able to get these values but I cannot find any setting to assign a specific printer tray.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code to set default Page Size in C#

```
    PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("papersize", 200, 100);//set the paper size
```

PaperSize accepts parameters NewPageSizeName, Width, Height